# PriorityBlockingQueue stream in Java 8 is out of order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, priority-queue

These two pieces of code have different order of output.
First piece:

```
while(!jobQueue.isEmpty()) {
    TimeoutJobRequest job = jobQueue.peek();
    if(job.isReady()) {
        execute(job);
        jobQueue.poll();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Second piece:

```
jobQueue.stream()
        .filter(TimeoutJobRequest::isReady)
        .peek(jobQueue::remove)
        .forEach(this::execute);
```

Note that `jobQueue` is a `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

The reordering occurs only when `this::execute` is relatively long (like for a couple of seconds.)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `PriorityBlockingQueue#stream` does not order the elements by queue priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `stream` of `PriorityBlockingQueue` follows the `Iterator` order, which according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to
>   traverse the elements of the PriorityBlockingQueue in any particular
>   order.

If you want the priority order, you need to `poll` the elements from the `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
pq.add(5);
pq.add(8);
pq.add(3);

System.out.println("-- Try 1 --");
pq.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println("-- Try 2 --");
IntStream.range(0, pq.size()).map(i -> pq.poll()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (it may depend on Java implementation):

```
-- Try 1 --
3
8
5
-- Try 2 --
3
5
8
```

Comment: Note that `stream().sorted()` should also work (and probably even faster than polling each element).

Comment: Good point! Although with my approach, we don't need to care about what is the order underlying the  `PriorityBlockingQueue`, as it could have been initialized with a `Comparator`. It's true that in that case, we could also use `stream().sorted(pq.comparator())`, but we need to be careful, because the `sorted` doesn't like `null`s.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a stream that follows the queue order you can try the following code (it empties the queue):

```
Stream.generate(jobQueue::poll).limit(jobQueue.size())
```

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code is not equal to the second one, when the `job.isReady()` function returns `false`, the first one terminate, but the second still run, the function `filter` of stream is only a filtering operation

you can change the first piece of code to

```
while(!jobQueue.isEmpty()) {
    TimeoutJobRequest job = jobQueue.peek();
    if(job.isReady()) {
        execute(job);
        jobQueue.poll();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, iteration order != priority order.

I prepared two copy-paste'able solutions for using Stream API for traversing a `PriorityQueue` using the priority order:

```
static <T> Stream<T> drainToStream(PriorityQueue<T> queue) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(queue);
    return Stream.generate(queue::poll)
      .limit(queue.size());
}

static <T> Stream<T> asStream(PriorityQueue<T> queue) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(queue);
    Comparator<? super T> comparator = queue.comparator();
    return comparator != null
      ? queue.stream().sorted(comparator)
      : queue.stream().sorted();
}
```

The `draintToStream` empties the queue, whereas the `asStream` remains the original queue intact.

Comment: Works great, thanks Grzegorz. When `asStream()` is included as an instance method, the body reduces all the way down to just `this.stream().sorted(comparator)`. Really nice and simple.